# a general rule of transformation into 1st order hyperbolic PDEs

Tags: hyperbolic-pde

$u_{tt}=u_{xx}$ can be transformed into 1st order hyperbolic PDEs by letting $a=u_t$, $b=u_x$, which yields

$a_t=b_x$ and $b_t=a_x$, or

$(a,b)_t=(b,a)_x$

Is there a general rule to transform a general high order hyperbolic PDE (even 4th or 6th order spatial derivatives) into first order hyperbolic PDEs?

Comment: They all can be transformed into a system of first order PDEs.

Comment: thanks a lot but how

Comment: Have you tried with a 3rd order PDE?

Comment: yes but didn't succeed, for those with utt and uxxx, uxxxx etc

Comment: Keep in mind that a hyperbolic PDDE of, say, 3rd order is always of the form $$ u_{ttt} + au_{ttx} + bu_{txx} + cu_{xxx} + \text{ lower order terms} = f. $$ Now you try to do something analogous to what is done for a 2nd order hyperbolic PDE. I don't recall the details, but I think you might be able to figure it out by trial and error.

Comment: Once the equation is in [Cauchy-Kovalevskaya](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cauchy-Kovalevskaya_theorem) form $\partial_t^{n+1} u = F(\partial_t^{\le n} u)$, introduce the extra variables $u_k$, $k=1,\ldots,n$, and the extra equations $\partial_t u_{k-1} = u_k$, $k=1,\ldots,n-1$, with $u_0 = u$. Using these variables the order the original equation is reduced to 1, and altogether these variables satisfy a first order system, equivalent to the original equation.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine many thanks Prof Khavkine, for example how should I transform utt+uxxxx=0 to 1st order eqs?

Comment: @DeaneYang many thanks Prof Yang, for example how should I transform utt+uxxxx=0 to 1st order eqs?

Comment: That I don't know. Is that a hyperbolic PDE?

Comment: @DeaneYang Yes yes

Comment: $u_{tt} + u_{xxxx} = 0$ is equivalent to the first order system $u_t = u_1$, $(u_1)_t + u_{xxxx} = 0$. There is nothing particularly deep about it. I don't know what your notion of "hyperbolic" is, but this example doesn't fit any flavor of hyperbolicity that I know. Maybe you want to refer to the larger class of "evolutionary equations", which are may for instance be investigated by semigroup methods. Parabolic equations fit into that class.

Comment: Perhaps you could say where this PDE arises?

Comment: @DeaneYang arises from a bridge vibrating transversely

Comment: @IgorKhavkine this equation is conservative as opposed to dissipative so I think it's hyperbolic isn't it? Your 1st order system has uxxxx, which isn's 1st order. Can this system be broken down into a 1st order system with only 1st order derivatives?

Comment: I don’t believe this can be written as a reasonable system of first order PDEs. Here, by reasonable, I mean that there are the same number of unknown functions as equations and the system can be solved with real analytic data at $t=0$ using Cauchy-Kovalevski. In the same sense that the heat equation also cannot be written this way. But any PDE can be written as a first order system where the number of equations is greater than the number of unknown functions.

Comment: "Hyperbolic" does not have a unique meaning in general. You have not stated your definition, so any statement that has been made about hyperbolicity here is at best ambiguous. In your example, you can reduce the order with respect to $x$-derivatives in exactly the same way as I showed for $t$-derivatives, increasing the number of unknowns. As Deane Yang mentioned this can be done for any equation independent of type (even if it has no definite type). Summing up the whole discussion, it seems the answer to your original question (as written) is No.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers Profs Yang and Khavkine